# Making in-app phone calls on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, phone-call

Is it possible to develop an app that can make/start a (GSM) phone call without being forwarded to the actual dialer/phone application?

The purpose would be to provide on-screen information to the user along with the call-in-progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, to use GSM, it is not possible. You will have to direct that to the dialer. I believe you can develop some sort of solution, if you jailbreak, not sure if that is what you want.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html